# Type of function to swap arguments of a function

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming

So I made these functions to swap the arguments of functions

```
swap1_3 f x y z = f z y x

toFront3 f x y z = f z x y
```

These functions work as follows

```
foo x y z = [x,y,z]
a = foo 1 2 3 -- returns [1,2,3]
b = swap1_3 foo 1 2 3 -- returns [3,2,1]
c = toFront3 foo 1 2 3 -- returns [3,1,2]
```

Now, what I don't understand are the type signatures of these functions.

The type signatures are as follows

```
swap1_3 :: (a -> b -> c -> d) -> c -> b -> a -> d

toFront3 :: (a -> b -> c -> d) -> b -> c -> a -> d
```

From just looking at

```
swap1_3
```

one would think that

```
a corresponds to the type of x
b corresponds to the type of y
c corresponds to the type of z
d corresponds to the return type of f
```

but, when you look at the second half of the the type signature of

```
toFront3
```

it seems like there isn't that correspondence.

So, what's going on here?

Comment: "`d` corresponds to the return type of `f`" — it's quite ok to say that, but _actually_, `b->c->d` correspondents to the return type of `f`, whose only argument is `a`!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bit confusing, but look at it this way

```
f       :: a -> b -> c -> d
f z     ::      b -> c -> d
f z x   ::           c -> d
f z x y ::                d
```

Which implies

```
z :: a
x :: b
y :: c
```

So, we have

```
toFront3
    :: (a -> b -> c -> d)       -- f
    -> b                        -- x
    -> c                        -- y
    -> a                        -- z
toFront3 f x y z = f z x y
```

Comment: OOOOOOOOOHHHHHHHH! I see now! Thank you so much. I completely forgot that on the right side of the equation, I was going to apply f to z then x then y. So, obviously in the input I fed it in a jumbled up order. Thank you. It totally clicked.

Comment: :) :) :) And _that_, fellow stackoverflow users, is called teaching and learning happening. Well done both of you.

Comment: @TheSeamau5 No problem!  I was initially puzzled by it myself, it just took a minute of looking at the types to figure out exactly what was going on.  I figured the easiest way to show how it worked was with the incremental and annotated type signatures.  Sometimes a bit of whitespace can make all the difference in the world when trying to understand how something works.

Answer (score 2):

I'm often confused by the types of these sorts of function-transforming functions for a minute before I think about them. Another good way of looking at them is to add unnecessary parentheses to their types, and look at them like this:

```
toFront3 :: (a -> b -> c -> d) -> (b -> c -> a -> d)
```

That is, `toFront3` takes a function of 3 arguments, and gives you a function of the same arguments in a different order.

To have some names:

```
let g = toFront3 f
```

`g` and `f` are both functions of 3 arguments. `g` is going to call `f` after shuffling its 3rd argument to the front. Therefore the arguments `g` will receive are the *pre-shuffled* arguments. So to go from `f :: a -> b -> c -> d` to the type of `g` we have to apply the *inverse* shuffling of arguments that `toFront3` does, so that shuffling them will restore the argument order to `a -> b -> c -> d`, as is required to be passed to `f` post-shuffle.

Comment: Thanks. The parentheses help. Turns out, it makes so much more sense if you shuffle the input types. 

    toFront3 :: (c -> a -> b -> d) -> (a -> b -> c -> d)

I know that this is just a cosmetic change, but it is so much clearer. It says that toFront3 accepts a function of 3 arguments and 3 arguments. The first argument of f is of type the third argument of toFront3, the second argument of f is of type the first argument of toFront3, the third argument of f is of type the second argument of toFront3.